# Using Conditional Statement to Evaluate Column, Calculate, and Create New Colum in Dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've been working with combinations of if/else if statement for a bit and can't seem to get the desired outcome. I want the code to look at two columns in the dataframe `top` and `bottom`. If the data is missing for either, the new column should equal the value that is not `0`. If both `top` and `bottom` values are present, the column should be populated with the average. Also, if both values are `0`, the new value will also be `0`.

```
df$new <- if (df$top > 0 
            && df$bottom == 0){
            (df[["top"]])  
} else if (df$top == 0 
          && df$bottom > 0){
          (df[["bottom"]])  
} else if (df$top > 0 
          && df$bottom > 0){
          (df[["top"]] + df[["bottom"]])/2
}
```

Currently, when I run the code it's creating a new column `new` but only populating with `(top + bottom)/2` values.

As requested
`df <- data.frame(top = c(0, 2, 1, 4), bottom = c(1, 4, 0, 6))`

and output...

```
       top  bottom  new
    1   0     1      1
    2   2     4      3
    3   1     0      1 
    4   4     6      5
```

Comment: can you post a desired output?

Comment: (1) Please share an example of your data, best using `dput(head(df))` and your desired output given that data. Hit the "Edit" button and put the `structure` output there. (2) It seems to me that you are looking for a vectorized version of `if`. Try `ifelse` instead or, since you are using multiple conditions try `dplyr`'s `case_when` function.

Comment: Updated above. Apologies, I'm pretty new to R.

Comment: "If the data is missing for either, the new column should equal the value that is not 0" what if the value is missing in top and bottom has 0? what should be assigned? when you referring to values missing do mean NA or 0?

Comment: I'm referring to ```0``` all ```NA's``` have been converted to ```0```. As for when both ```top``` and ```bottom``` are equal to `0`, a return value of `0` is sufficient therefore the `(top+bottom)/2` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifelse` and `&` which are used for vectorized operations. `if` and `&&` work for the single value (first value) and the same operation is repeated for all the rows of the data.

```
df <- transform(df, new = ifelse(top > 0 & bottom == 0, top, 
                        ifelse(top == 0 & bottom > 0, bottom, (top + bottom)/2)))
df

#  top bottom new
#1   0      1 1.0
#2   2      4 3.0
#3   0      0 0.0
#4   5      6 5.5
```

You can also use `case_when` from `dplyr` here -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(top > 0 & bottom == 0 ~ top, 
                         top == 0 & bottom > 0 ~ bottom, 
                         TRUE ~ (top + bottom)/2))
```

---

Using this on the real data I would first use `janitor::clean_names()` to have clean column names which can be easily referred to. Then you can implement `case_when` for new columns as

```
Gagedf <- Gagedf %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(x_top_top_00095_00000 > 0 & x_bottom_bottom_00095_00000 == 0 ~ x_top_top_00095_00000, 
                         x_top_top_00095_00000 == 0 & x_bottom_bottom_00095_00000 > 0 ~ x_bottom_bottom_00095_00000, 
                         TRUE ~ (x_top_top_00095_00000 + x_bottom_bottom_00095_00000)/2))
```

Comment: There may be an issue with my column name headings, I've tried the recommended script with no luck and have also tried to rename the column heading to simplify with no luck. The data is downloaded from the USGS site so I'm not sure if there's an issue because of that.

Comment: These are my actual column headings automattically generated during the download ```names(Gagedf)
 [1] "agency_cd"                         "site_no"                           "dateTime"                         
 [4] "X_TOP...Top._00095_00000"          "X_TOP...Top._00095_00000_cd"       "X_BOTTOM...Bottom._00095_00000"   
 [7] "X_BOTTOM...Bottom._00095_00000_cd" "X_TOP...Top._00480_00000"          "X_TOP...Top._00480_00000_cd"      
[10] "X_BOTTOM...Bottom._00480_00000"    "X_BOTTOM...Bottom._00480_00000_cd" "tz_cd"```

Comment: Well, there are multiple top and bottom columns in your actual data. The sample data has only one. How do you want to compare them? You can provide sample of your actual data using `dput(head(Gagedf))` and show expected output for it to make the question clear.

Comment: There are mutiple top and bottom values, however they are named with specific parameter codes ie: ```X_TOP...Top._00095_00000``` and they will be compared to like parameters. However, I'm only looking at one at the moment. I've tried to rename the column headings for simplicity, but I can't seem to do that either.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? ```> dput(head(Gagedf)) 
structure(list(agency_cd = c("USGS", "USGS", "USGS", "USGS", 
"USGS", "USGS"), site_no = c("301124081395901", "301124081395901", 
"301124081395901", "301124081395901", "301124081395901", "301124081395901"
), dateTime = structure(c(1514782800, 1514784600, 1514786400, 
1514788200, 1514790000, 1514791800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), X_TOP...Top._00095_00000 = c(468, 469, 469, 
````
 Too long to show all

Comment: Could the ```type``` being a ```list``` be an issue?

Comment: You can edit your post to include the `dput` output.

Comment: Sorry, again new to R and SO. Is the above comment not what you are looking for?

Comment: It is but the main top and bottom columns are not included in it so I cannot use it. `dput` is used to makes it easier for us to use your data as it is so we don't have to recreate the data like how did in my answer. If you edit your post to include the complete `dput` output it would be helpful.

Comment: Here's just the top and bottom parameters isolated ```dput(head(Gagedf[,c(4,6)]))
structure(list(X_TOP...Top._00095_00000 = c(468, 469, 469, 468, 
468, 471), X_BOTTOM...Bottom._00095_00000 = c(468, 469, 469, 
468, 468, 471)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: I have updated answer to make it work on your actual data. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked with the dataset I have. Was there an issue with the column names?

Comment: Yes, these are non standard column names so it is helpful to change them to something which is easier to use. `janitor::clean_names()` is easy way to do that.